# Limit hibernate stored procedure parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm using hibernate in my application and when persisting a large set (~450 objects each with 6 or 7 fields) for the first time hibernate tries to persist it all in one go and results in a sqlGrammarException with a message

"The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request."

This seems like something that the sql dialect should configure.

I looked and couldn't find anything relevant.

I am using mssql 2012 hibernate 4 and java 1.6.

I would prefer to not have to take care of this manually as it seems like something that could be taken care of with the proper configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you only general answer:

This is limitation of MsSQL. You cannot execute sql with more then 2100 parameters.

You have to split your query into multiple queries. Or somehow reduce number of parameters...

Comment: that is the conclusion we came to as well